# How to prevent XBMC from shutting down or suspending your computer?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, xbmc

Since I run XBMC as a program, and not standalone, I would just like it to exit when I click the power button. The default behavior is to show the shutdown menu, and I don't want to accidently shut down my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Remap the Power button on the home screen to quit xbmc instead of showing the shutdown menu:**
You should modify the `Home.xml` file in your skin folder in `/usr/share/xbmc`. For me (Frodo RC3 with the Confluence skin) this is `/usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml`.

In this file you need to replace the line (in my case line 1067, see bottom of the post on how to quickly open the file at that position)

```
<onclick>ActivateWindow(ShutdownMenu)</onclick>
```

by

```
<onclick>XBMC.Quit()</onclick>
```

Now if you click the power button in XBMC it should just exit, without showing a menu.
You need to do this again after XBMC updates since it overwrites the files in `/usr/share/xbmc`.

---

**Alternatives / Notes**
With the above solution you can still shutdown XBMC using a remote, or the web interface.

Instead of doing the above (simply quiting, not showing the shutdown menu) you can also edit the shutdown menu instead. The menu itself is in `/usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/DialogButtonMenu.xml`. The interesting menu buttons are defined from line 73 and down. The shutdown button (`id=3`) has the property

```
<visible>System.CanPowerDown</visible>
```

changing this to

```
<visible>no</visible>
```

should hide it from the menu. You can do the same trick for suspend, reboot, etc.

This still doesn't prevent shutting down from the webinterface I think,
If only I knew how to set `System.CanPowerDown=false`...
If you know it please add it in the comments.

---

**Extra: Commands to quickly open the file at the right position (1067,33)**

- Vim (If you don't know it, try to learn it, it is very nice!)

  ```
  sudo vim /usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml +1067
  ```

  or even better (independent of actual line number)

  ```
  sudo vim /usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml +/ShutdownMenu
  ```
- Nano (terminal editor that is easy to use for beginners)

  ```
  sudo nano +1067,33 /usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml
  ```
- Gedit (Simple GUI editor)

  ```
  gksudo gedit /usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml +1067
  ```

Comment: Yeah!. I thought this was not possible. Can you also add the following so it is easier to go to it:

sudo nano +1067,33 /usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml

Or sudo gedit +1067 /usr/share/xbmc/addons/skin.confluence/720p/Home.xml

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: Thanks, I edited the answer, I think I will contact someone from the xbmc community to see how I can set `System.CanPowerDown=false`. That would be a nice alternative.

Comment: Yes it will. It will save me and I think everybody I know that uses XBMC a headache or two.

Comment: On the xmbc irc they thought it was not possible, they suggested to run xbmc as user without shutdown/suspend privileges. I thought that was too much trouble. Instead I made I feature request: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=151278&pid=1290873#pid1290873